# Spring Configuration with annotations @Autowired not working - step by step

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I have performed this steps in order to use annotation based configuration:

a) beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.*"/>

</beans>
```

b) then I have this component:

```
package test;
@Component
public class InMemoryUserService implements UserService
```

c) then I try to use autowire:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;
```

and in runtime `userService` is null.

Basic stuff is set up properly (like dependencies etc.) because in first version of the test app I was using xml based configuration and it was working smoothly.

And this is a class that uses autowireing:

```
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public DemoApplication() {
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DemoApplication da = new DemoApplication();
        da.userService.getUserByEmail("blabla@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Please show the code of the class where you want to autowire the UserService.

Comment: I've added it. It's just a console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because -

- `DemoApplication` is not a spring managed bean. Make it spring managed by adding `@Component` similar to `UserService`.
- Use spring bean factory or application context, say `ClasspathXMLApplicationContext`, to get the `DemoApplication` instead of `new` operator.

Answer (score -1):

How will spring know  that it has to run this DemoApplication.

You have to run it with a `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` something like below:

Annotate your DemoApplication  as shown below:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration
    public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testBean() {
     userService.getUserByEmail("");
    }

    }
```

Comment: This would be correct for a unit test, however DemoApplication is no unit test.